# LINQ to SQL: Assign variable to data context table?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a method that takes in a string value for the table name for the purpose of binding data to a grid.  I've been manually typing the lambda LINQ expressions for each table and I want to reduce this to a single line.  How can I assign a variable to the context table?

```
    public void BindDropDown(DropDownList ddl, string tableName)
    {
        using (RequisitionModelContainer context = new RequisitionModelContainer())
        {
            var queryReqDepartments = context.ReqDepartments.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
            var reqDepartment = queryReqDepartments.ToList();
            var queryDepartmentCats = context.DepartmentCats.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
            var departmentCats = queryDepartmentCats.ToList();
            var queryTitleCats = context.TitleCats.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
            var titleCats = queryTitleCats.ToList();
            var queryPurposeCats = context.PurposeCats.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
            var purposeCats = queryPurposeCats.ToList();

            //Switch statement takes in a table name and binds table data to the drop down list
            switch (tableName)
            {    
                case "ReqDepartments":
                    ddl.DataSource = reqDepartment;
                    BindList(ddl, reqDepartment);
                    break;
                case "DepartmentCats":
                    ddl.DataSource = departmentCats;
                    BindList(ddl, departmentCats);
                    break;
                case "TitleCats":
                    ddl.DataSource = titleCats;
                    BindList(ddl, titleCats);
                    break;
                case "PurposeCats":
                    ddl.DataSource = purposeCats;
                    BindList(ddl, purposeCats);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
private static IDictionary<string,Func<RequisitionModelContainer, IQueryable>> tableProviders;

public static MyClass() //your class' static constructor
{
    tableProviders = new Dictionary<string,Func<RequisitionModelContainer, IQueryable>> 
    {
        {"ReqDepartments", context => context.ReqDepartments.OrderBy(c => c.Name)},
        {"DepartmentCats", context => context.DepartmentCats.OrderBy(c => c.Name)},
        {"TitleCats", context => context.TitleCats.OrderBy(c => c.Name)},
        {"PurposeCats", context => context.PurposeCats.OrderBy(c => c.Name)}
    };
}

public void BindDropDown(DropDownList ddl, string tableName)
{
    using (RequisitionModelContainer context = new RequisitionModelContainer())
    { 
        var data = tableProviders[tableName](context);
        ddl.DataSource = data;
        BindList(ddl, data);
    }
}
```